# IEnumerable from a View c# MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not very experienced in SQL.  I am using SQL Server 2008, and MVC3; have a simple view in my Database, trying to make a list using the following script:

```
 List<vw_LearnerCourse> list = ctx.vw_LearnerCourses.Where(x => x.Course_ID == id).ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<vw_LearnerCourse>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<vw_LearnerCourse>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Would appreciate your assistance.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on the IEnumerable.

```
List<vw_LearnerCourse> list = ctx.vw_LearnerCourses.Where(x => x.Course_ID == id).ToList();
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

> The ToList(IEnumerable) method forces immediate
>   query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query
>   results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a
>   cached copy of the query results.

Comment: Am I missing something: that's excatly the same code as the OP posted saying there was a problem with it?

Comment: You are right, one of my edits reverted some of the code.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
 List<vw_LearnerCourse> list 
          = ctx.vw_LearnerCourses.Where(x => x.Course_ID == id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) that List is defined as

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
IEnumerable
```

by default List is Enumerable. So it works fine if you end the statement with ToList(). NO need of AsEnumerable().

```
List<vw_LearnerCourse> list = ctx.vw_LearnerCourses.Where(x => x.Course_ID == id).ToList();
```